# resizable grid column with image next and prev

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to make a website builder based on grid column.

To make the columns I want to resize the width with images using [jQuery UI library](http://jqueryui.com/resizable/), I do not find the option to use image resizing.

Is it possible to resize with `next` and `prev` images arrows?.

Here I have this example but without arrows:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#resizable" ).resizable({
      grid: 50
    });
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wDu3L/6)

Can you help please?

Comment: That's not how you make a fiddle. Put css, javascript, html separately.

Comment: @OptimusPrime I've updated

Comment: .resizable makes image resizable using mouse, not using any keys. If you wish to add those keys, please add to your fiddle and update with the next and prev keys. Than I may help you with javascript. It seems you haven't tried anything.

Comment: @OptimusPrime I've updated in http://jsfiddle.net/wDu3L/6/, but I find nothing in the api documentation. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here,

```
$('#prev').click(function(){  
     $("#resizable").css({"width": $("#resizable").width()-10});
});
$('#next').click(function(){
     $("#resizable").css({"width": $("#resizable").width()+10});
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wDu3L/8/)**

Comment: oh my good  ,that easy and I've seen looking at the api. I liked your answer. It is better to do it yourself to try to find the solution in the api of jquery ui resize. Thansk!!!!! @OptimusPrime